# Forcing type parameter to implement specific method in java generics

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to force type parameter in java generics to implement `equals` method?
For example, I wrote this class: `public class Bag<Item> implements Iterable<Item>` which has `contains` method, that uses `Item.equals` method. So I want to make sure that the passed  Object in the generics will also implement the `equals` method.

Comment: You'll want to make an **interface** class and pass that as the type parameter.

Comment: All objects already implement `equals()`.

Comment: I think you mean that passed objects must be forced to override `equals`, but this is... well, weird.

Comment: The only way you can force an object to override `equals` is with a nasty reflection hack that will fail at runtime instead of at compile time.

Comment: @MrD: There would be no requirement for the implementing class to override the default implementation of `equals()`.  If you had a `ProvideEquals` interface that defines `boolean equals();`, any class could satisfiably implement it with no further work.

Comment: @Jeffrey: And even then there's no guarantee that the override does anything other than `return super.equals(obj);`, so there's absolutely no point.

Comment: @kiheru I can write MyClass that not implements equals

Comment: Just because you do not write an equals method, does not mean the class does not implement one. All classes have a default `equals()`, unless they provide another implementation (the default is equivalent to `==`).

Answer (score 8):

You could make an abstract base class called `ItemBase`, make equals abstract and then have `Item extend ItemBase`.

```
public abstract class ItemBase {

  @Override
  public abstract boolean equals(Object o);
}

public class Bag extends ItemBase
```

This would force anyone Implementing ItemBase to specifically implement equals

Comment: Would love to know why Java allows this.  To me, it's a pretty major violation of polymorphism and violates the principle of least surprise (why is it so different than interfaces?)

Comment: To answer my own question, it is explicitly allowed by the JLS (*"An instance method that is not abstract can be overridden by an abstract method."*), and gives some examples: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e10777.  I still question the value however.

Comment: @MarkPeters I've used this pattern for the base class of types that were meant to be used as keys in hashtable-like structures. I wanted to "remind" the implementor (who might not be me) that it didn't make sense not to override `hashCode` and `equals`.